# Node js mongoose multiple photo data buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello gooday everyone.

just a quick question here. how can I make this multiple photo  my model looks like this

for my model

```
new mongoose.Schema({
 photo: {
  data: Buffer,
  contentType: String
 },
})
```

and for my controller

```
if (files.photo) {
  post.photo.data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
  post.photo.contentType = files.photo.type;
}
post.save((err, result) => {});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its real simple.

For model

```
new mongoose.Schema({
 photos: [{
  data: Buffer,
  contentType: String
 }],
})
```

and for controller

```
if (files.photos && files.photos.length > 0) {
  post.photos=[];
  for (let photo in files.photo){
    let data = fs.readFileSync(files.photo.path);
    let contentType = files.photo.type;
    post.photos.push({
      data, contentType
    })
  }
}
post.save((err, result) => {});
```

Comment: I think it should be `&& files.photos.length > 0` (with an "s") and `for (let photo in files.photos){` (with "files."), or else it seems good!

Comment: Corrected  as per the typo

Comment: it doesnt go in the condition if(files.photos). and if i use files.photo.length it says cannot read property 'length'

Comment: you need to send the files in the photos tab not the photo one and if you are using an express middleware make sure that you allow multiple files to parsed otherwise you will get a single file.

Comment: is there any other way than for? it loops many times like 10 loops even i only send 2 files